# Data load from Excel to SQL Server - Data Type Issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server, data-transfer

How do I load data from Excel to SQL server with the correct data type? When I load the data, a column in Excel having 'double' values, changes to 'Strings'.

Comment: Please, describe the steps you're following to load the data to SQL Server and the version of SQl Server.

Comment: You may refer to [Import data from Excel to SQL Server or Azure SQL Database](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for help. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks guys,
Changing the Data Type while importing and Ignoring the Data Type Conversion error solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, 
Changing the Data Type while importing and Ignoring the Data Type Conversion error solved the issue.
While running import wizard, there is an option to check data type conversion, uncheck that to avoid this error. I hope this answer your question

Comment: Could you expand a little on what you changed to solve your issue?

Comment: While running import wizard, there is an option to check data type conversion, uncheck that to avoid this error. I hope this answer your question.

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to include that information. Please see [answer] and take our [tour].